# ListPrice does not fill automatically on Order Products Selection layout

Tags: pricebook, order, pricebookentry, orderitem

Whenever I add Order Products to an Order, they appear with empty ListPrices on the layout. Meaning that the field shows up but it is always blank.

The Parent PriceBook and its entries are activated and all related products have a Standard PriceBookEntry.

How can I fix this? With OpportunityLineItems this is standard functionality.

Comment: which layout? the one on the Order detail page or the Order Products selection screen.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000333442&type=1 Does this answer your question?

Comment: @cropredy the Order Products selection screen

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi Unfortunately no. The page references Opportunities and Products.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Page Layout and click the Edit Multi-Line Layout link. You will get a page that looks like this:

[image]